# FileNotFoundException Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a problem loading a file in my java applet. Basically, in my class Pixel2, I instantiate an instance of another class Stack which take a file name as an argument and load that file (here I try track.txt)
I have my file "track.txt" at the root of my project

[image: image1]

but when I try to run my applet, I get a filenotfound exception.

[image]

The weird thing is that if i run an instance of the class Stack in a test class, the file is loading correctly!

I am really confused, is there a special way to handle the load of file in an applet? Should files be put into a specific repository in order to be detected by the methods inside the scope of the applet?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Applets are running in a sandbox: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html On a side note, browsers like [chrome are dropping applet support](https://www.quora.com/How-will-Java-be-supported-in-Chrome-after-Chrome-drops-the-NPAPI-support) - better use an HTML5 approach or, if you require client side Java, check out [webstart](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_web_start_in_or)

Answer (score 1):

An applet has a security manager that limits access to the file system.

Here however you are accessing a file inside the application. The application could be packed in a jar and hence the "file" be zipped, read-only needing unzipping. For this java uses the concept of **resource**. A resource such as `Lumi/track.txt" has a case sensitive path with slash.

Change the usage in Stack to using an InputStream, like:

```
public Stack(String resourcePath) {
    InputStream in = Stack.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharset.UTF_8))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The error being that File would access the local file system, and the relative path is *not* in src/Lumi/.

Comment: Many thanks Joop! I just change the path from track.txt to Lumi/track.txt and it worked :)